# how many triggers can a single instance of SchedulerFactory have?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

My application may fire around 1000's or more triggers everyday. Each of these is categorized into 4 categories:

- morning(9am)
- afternoon(1pm)
- evening(6pm)
- night(10pm)

And at each of these times, there will be 100's of trigger fired. Below is code

```
SchedulerFactory schdFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler schd;
for(ecah morningSchedulers){
  // some logic for instantiating trigger
  AbstractTrigger trigger = (AbstractTrigger) newTrigger().withSchedule(cronSchedule("0     0"+mAlert+"0,0,0 * * ?")).build();
  trigger.setStartTime(strtDat);
  trigger.setEndTime(endDat);
  final JobDetail job = newJob(AlertJob.class).build();
  schd.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

I have 2 questions here

1. Should I instantiate scheduler inside for loop or outside and schedule many triggers to the same scheduler. i.e. schd = schdFact.getScheduler(); where should I write this line?(inside or outside for loop)
2. I have to reschedule some of these triggers. i.e. stop on some condition and start again.

Answer (score 0):

> how many triggers can a single instance of SchedulerFactory have?

There is a similar question in the official [FAQ](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq#FAQ-scale):

> ## How many jobs is Quartz capable of running?
>
> This is a tough question to answer... the answer is basically "it depends". [...] So, the limiting factor of the number of Triggers and Jobs Quartz can "store" and monitor is really the amount of storage space available to the JobStore (either the amount of RAM or the amount of disk space).

Also remember about this:

> [...] The actual number of jobs that can be running at any moment in time is limited by the size of the thread pool. If there are five threads in the pool, no more than five jobs can run at a time.

If you have thousands of **triggers** (you aren't confusing triggers and trigger executions?), consider JDBC storage. But if you have only few triggers but running several times a day, RAM store is enough.

> Should I instantiate scheduler inside for loop or outside and schedule many triggers to the same scheduler

Definitely have only a **single** scheduler for the whole application. It is rare to have more than one scheduler in an application, see: [Utilizing Multiple (Non-Clustered) Scheduler Instances](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/MultipleSchedulers).

Create the scheduler once and treat as a singleton.

> I have to reschedule some of these triggers. i.e. stop on some condition and start again.

This is, again, explained in the documentation: [Updating an existing Trigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger). Basically you need to know the trigger key:

```
// retrieve the trigger
Trigger oldTrigger = sched.getTrigger(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1");

// obtain a builder that would produce the trigger
TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

// update the schedule associated with the builder, and build the new trigger
// (other builder methods could be called, to change the trigger in any desired way)
Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
    .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
    .withRepeatCount(10)
    .build();

sched.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
```

BTW if just want to run a job at a given single hour, there is an easier API. Instead of:

```
newTrigger().
  withSchedule(
    cronSchedule("0     0"+mAlert+"0,0,0 * * ?")
  ).
  build()
```

You can simply say:

```
newTrigger().
  withSchedule(
    dailyAtHourAndMinute(mAlert, 42)
  ).
  build();
```

Have a look at [Lesson 6: CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) of the official tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for links. Yes I have thousands of triggers. What you mean by trigger and trigger execution? My application will send sms's to patients at these 4 times I defined. And each user has several prescriptions. Each of these prescriptions has start and end date. So in this case I have to start several triggers right? because each of them have different data only similarity is timing(9am,1pm,5pm and 10pm).     So do I have to store these triggers in database or something? Thats what u meant by jdbc storage. How that will help me?

Comment: @Preethi: When you reach hundreds of thousands of patients, the triggers will occupy a lot of memory. Also you must remember about recreating the triggers after restart. And what if your application was down during that period? Your general approach is very good, but consider having only 4 triggers (one per each hour) and send batch SMS to all patients that should take a medicine at a given time. This might scale better.